# next jquery don't work and my code is true

Tags: php, jquery, html

My jQuery codes doesn't work, and I can't find why. The code seems to be ok.

My html code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning Jquery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" disabled="disabled">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myjquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
        $(this).next().removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add relevant html

Comment: Can you add the html etc to display what you're trying to do? Have you tried JSFiddle or something to try your code?

Comment: is the target element a sibling?

Comment: We need to see your HTML to be able to even begin to help you.  What do you expect `$(this).next()` to select?

Comment: Note: File inputs do *not* fire the onchange event properly in older browsers IE <= 8, FF 3.5 etc. Which browser are you experiencing this?

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean?

Comment: The _next_ element after your file input field is the `<br>` element – and “disabling” that is rather pointless :-) But you can provide next() with a selector as well, so just have it select the next ìnput` element.

Comment: @CBroe hit the nail on the head. You need to do .next('input')

Comment: @CBroe: That's not what the parameter to `next` does.  `.next('input')` would get the next element (which is a `<br/>`), compare it to the paramter (`'input'`), then return a empty jQuery object since `'br' !== 'input'`.

Comment: On a side note, I would recommend against using `.removeAttr()`. Try using `.prop('disabled', false)` instead.

Comment: @JoeSpurling: That won't work.

Comment: @Rocket, you’re right.

Comment: @CBroe: What *would* work is `.nextAll('input')`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable your submit button, then try this javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
        $(this).closest('form').find('[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yep, `.prop()` is probably the better alternative compared to `.removeAttr()`

Comment: His `<input>`s aren't in a `<form>`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I'd say it's because the OP stripped too much of its html. As there is a `submit input`, there must be a `<form>`. At least I hope.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhh yeah it works thank you very much i though it will take long time to get an answer thank you very much

Comment: @user2174729 - you should check this as the solution/accepted answer by clicking the check to the left of it.

Comment: @user2174729 ALSO word of caution - use it as here setting it to false and do NOT use `removeProp()` as once removed, a property cannot be re-added.

Answer (score 1):

[`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) selects the immediately following sibling of the element you chose, which in your case would be a break (`<br />`). Try instead:

```
$(this).siblings('input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UMRvw/)**